# angular $http get all headers

Tags: ajax, angularjs

**TL;DR;**

I want to get all headers from the `$http` service and display them to the page. I don't care if it is only a list of the keys or the key/value pairs.

- How can I do this?
- Why has what I have been doing not working?

**What I want to do**

```
  $http
    .get( '/data/?some=parameters&go=here' )
    .success( function( response, status, headers ) {
      $scope.headers = headers();
    });
```

This outputs correctly in the Chrome console if I `console.log` either `headers()` or `$scope.headers`.

**Only thing that I can do that works**

```
  $http
    .get( '/data/?some=parameters&go=here' )
    .success( function( response, status, headers ) {
      $scope.headers['cache-control']     = headers('cache-control');
      $scope.headers['connection']        = headers('connection');
      $scope.headers['content-type']      = headers('content-type');
      $scope.headers['date']              = headers('date');
      $scope.headers['expires']           = headers('expires');
      $scope.headers['keep-alive']        = headers('keep-alive');
      $scope.headers['pragma']            = headers('pragma');
      $scope.headers['server']            = headers('server');
      $scope.headers['transfer-encoding'] = headers('transfer-encoding');
      $scope.headers['x-powered-by']      = headers('x-powered-by');
      // etc....
    });
```

This actually works in code, but I have to manually tell it every header to expect.

**Meanwhile in my view**

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="(key,value) in headers">
  <div class="col-xs-4 text-right">{{ key }}</div>
  <div class="col-xs-8 text-left">{{ value }}</div>
</div>
```

AngularJS v1.3.15 was hurt during the making of this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why and how `angular` produces the headers `object`, but the reason of this error is that the object has no `hasOwnProperty()` function, which is used by `ng-repeat` loop to avoid standard JS functions calls.

What I managed to do is simple copying of the properties in a newly created object to make it work:

```
$scope.headers = {}

var tmp = headers()

for (var key in tmp) {
  $scope.headers[key] = tmp[key]
}
```

See the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/r25N9B7FvRJGUOD61sqw?p=preview) as an example.